# Does TFS API WorkItemStore.BatchSave(WorkItem[]) method close the opened work items?

Tags: c#, tfs, workitem

Recently I came across an issue when I was trying to enhance the performance of updating work items in the data base using TFS API. I have more than a million work items to update and I separated them in tasks to enhance the performance. Unfortunately I have to Open and not just PartialOpen the work items and I was wondering if the WorkItemStore.BatchSave(WorkItem[]) method would close the work items and frees up the memory, or should I have to close the work items in the work item array myself? Does anybody has experience with this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "close" since it typically refers to the work item status but you use it in the same context as freeing memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the [Close method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff735731%28v%3dvs.120%29) states that

> Closes this WorkItem instance and frees memory that is associated with it.

`Save` and `BatchSave` don't do this. In fact you can inspect the result, tweak the object data and retry the operation.

Forgot to say:
check the [WorkItemStore.MaxBulkUpdateBatchSize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh986468%28v%3dvs.120%29) value to manage your batches.

Comment: Thank you Giulio, this helped me greatly!